# How to make error-chain errors compatible with Failure errors?

Tags: error-handling, rust

Given the following code:

```
extern crate dotenv; // v0.11.0
#[macro_use]
extern crate failure; // v0.1.1

#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
#[fail(display = "oh no")]
pub struct Error(dotenv::Error);
```

Due to the fact that `error-chain` (v0.11, the latest) does not guarantee that its wrapped error is `Sync` ([open PR to fix the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/error-chain/pull/241)) I get an error saying that `Sync` is not implemented for `dotenv::Error`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + 'static: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:17
  |
5 | #[derive(Debug, Fail)]
  |                 ^^^^ `std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + 'static` cannot be shared between threads safely
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + 'static`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Sync` for `std::ptr::Unique<std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + 'static>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + 'static>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + 'static>>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `error_chain::State`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `dotenv::Error`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `Error`
```

What's the minimal amount of boilerplate/work I can get away with to make these types play nicely together? The shortest thing I've been able to come up with is adding an `ErrorWrapper` newtype so that I can implement `Error` on an `Arc<Mutex<ERROR_CHAIN_TYPE>>`:

```
use std::fmt::{self, Debug, Display, Formatter};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
#[fail(display = "oh no")]
pub struct Error(ErrorWrapper<dotenv::Error>);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ErrorWrapper<T>(Arc<Mutex<T>>)
where
    T: Debug;

impl<T> Display for ErrorWrapper<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "oh no!")
    }
}

impl<T> ::std::error::Error for ErrorWrapper<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        "whoops"
    }
}

// ... plus a bit more for each `From<T>` that needs to be converted into
// `ErrorWrapper`
```

Is this the right way to go about it? Is there something that will have less code/runtime cost for converting into an `Arc<Mutex<T>>` for things that don't need it?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can suggest is to remove the `Arc` type.

If you have something that is not `Sync` then wrap into a `Mutex` type, so
to integrate `error-chain` with `failure` just wrap `dotenv::Error`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate failure;
extern crate dotenv;
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
#[fail(display = "oh no")]
pub struct Error(Mutex<dotenv::Error>);

fn main() {
    match dotenv::dotenv() {
        Err(e) => {
            let err = Error(Mutex::new(e));
            println!("{}", err)
        }
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @E_net4!

Comment: That is a good point that I don't need the `Arc` since I'm not actually sharing the value, just sending it.